# Where to find bootstrap classes' css definitons?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, class, definition

What I want is, for example, to change the css background color of navigations bar of .navbar-default, which can be done by .navbar-default{background-color:#000;}

But I want is, to see the full css style definitions of .navbar-default class, so I can look and change every element(text-color, hovering colors and every other thing) as I like. Rather than inspecting webpage elements for css codes from browsers, I want to look in a place where the definitions contain.

Comment: Within the `bootstrap.css` file or if you are using SASS some can be overridden using variables

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find all in readable format [here](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css)

Comment: Thanks, That's Great!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [`CDN`](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/) "version" of Bootstrap, then you won't be able to edit the `CSS`.

A good way to do what you want is by using your own *local* copy of the `bootstrap.css` file. You'll find herein all the definitions, and you can alter them as per your wish.

Conversely, you could also edit the `.sass` or `.less` files if you want more control.

> edit:

*Since the OP **is** using CDN*, follow the following steps and you should be just fine:

- Identify the *element/ tag* that you want to edit: `div`, `input`, etc.
- Identify the *attribute* you want to edit: `color`, `height`, etc.
- most importantly: identify the `class` or `id` of the element.

After you've done the above, create a new styles file, for example: `styles.css`, and write your new custom `CSS` rules in there as per CSS rules.

Include this file by linking it in your `.html` file using the `link` tag

*Voila!*

Comment: I'm using a cdn, but I can override it, inside in my webpages, no?

Comment: @slbgdp there you go

Comment: Thanks, what I wanted was to see where the definitions were in a readable format as where Gerard given in a link, so I can see what I would like to change. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This is for new version

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.css

Just check the header import link and remove .min part if its minimised link

Comment: Many thanks, and it appears to cover version from 3.2.0 to 5.3.2 (the latest) - just change the version code after @.

Answer (score 0):

> You can find and edit it in `bootstrap.min.css`