# How to check default specific CSS styles for a component in React-Bootstraps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-5, react-bootstrap

It has been difficult for me to find the `CSS` styles on a specific component in `React-Bootstrap`.

I have found another stackoverflow question: [Where to find bootstrap classes' css definitons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44387827/where-to-find-bootstrap-classes-css-definitons) that provides access to the overall `Bootstrap`'s `CSS` styles.

However, as I need to find the specific default `CSS` styles on `React-Bootstrap`, for example `NavDropDown` component, and the `React-Bootstrap` reimplements the `Bootstrap`'s `JavaScript` code. I have lost track to the goal.

Thank you for all the help, and please let me know if I am making any mistakes.

---

Update#1

`React-Bootstrap` has stated in the [website](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/docs/getting-started/introduction/#stylesheets) that it does not include any `CSS` styles by default:

> Stylesheets
> Because React-Bootstrap doesn't depend on a very precise version of Bootstrap, we don't ship with any included CSS. However, some stylesheet is required to use these components.

Then, how does it provide any pre-defined formatting to any of its components?